# Each time I push new data to the array of object, the name property becomes "undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, oop

Below is the class in which I try to push new data to the array of objects

```
 static addCustomer(input) {
        // buyTicket
        let data = Model.readCustomer();
        let theaterId = Number(input[0]);
        let name = input[1];
        let gender = input[2];
        let seatNumber = input[3];
        let ticketType = input[4];
        let custId = 1;
        let theaterName = "xxi";
        let movie = "movie";
    
        if (data.length !== 0) {
          custId = data[data.length - 1].id + 1;
        }
    
        switch (theaterId) {
          case 1:
            theaterName = "Cinema 12";
            movie = "Codezilla";
            break;
          case 2:
            theaterName = "Bioskop IXX";
            movie = "The Journey to Center of OOP";
            break;
          case 3:
            theaterName = "Moviemaxx";
            movie = "Avatar The Legend of Callback";
            break;
          case 4:
            theaterName = "VGCinema";
            movie = "Git The Kungfu Master";
            break;
          case 5:
            theaterName = "Bioskop IXX";
            movie = "Json The Protector";
            break;
    
          default:
            break;
        }
    
        let newCustomer = new Customer(
          custId,
          name,
          gender,
          new Ticket(theaterName, ticketType, movie, seatNumber)
        );
    
        data.push(newCustomer)
        console.log(data)
      }
```

This is the console.log result, you notice that the name property of the previous data becomes "undefined" each time I try to push new data to the array.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8byCf.png)

Below is my "Customer" class in which I import to the models.js file

```
class Customer {
  constructor(id, customerName, gender, ticket) {
    this.id = id;
    this.customerName = customerName;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.ticket = new Ticket(
      ticket.theaterName,
      ticket.type,
      ticket.movie,
      ticket.seatNumber
    );
  }
}

class Ticket {
  constructor(theaterName, type, movie, seatNumber) {
    this.theaterName = theaterName;
    this.type = type;
    this.movie = movie;
    this.seatNumber = seatNumber;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your `Customer` class?

Comment: Sure, I will add a picture of it

Comment: @NGAJISUBUH Pictures are highly discouraged for anything dealing with text. Even your console output could easily be included as text. When you need to use an image, it is best to embed the image rather than linking to it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, will update it

Comment: Where is `Model.readCustomer()` defined?

Comment: Can you show where you call addCustomer function

Comment: Are you sure when you get data from `Model.readCustomer();` the customerName is not undefined?

Comment: @JeffB in the same file as the addCustomer() class

Comment: Another tip, when you pare passing parameters into a function, it is best to spit them out. Instead of having an `input` array, have an input variable for each thing you want. IE `name`, `theaterId`, `gender` etc. Much easier to read.

Comment: @BibekGurung Yes, I teste it several times, it worked just fine, but suddenly when I tried to tested it again with different data , it became undefined

Comment: Maybe your new data format might be wrong.

Comment: We simply need more information to be able to know. Also you don't need to create a new ticket in your customer constructor as you already passed in a ticket object. Please also add the input data you are using that gave you the results in the screenshot.

Comment: If you `console.log(input)` at the top of the function, is element 1 `undefined`?  This would seem to be the case.